# Передача значений ArrayList в параметр массив для функции postgresql базы данных

Tags: массивы, postgresql, база-данных, java, функции

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но в одном моменте я никак не могу разобраться. Есть база данных Postgresql со следующей функцией-заглушкой

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net_train(terms text[], perceptron_id integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$begin
-- stub
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION net_train(text[], integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Как передать значения ArrayList-а в параметр массив термов для этой функции (также хотелось бы знать как передать второй параметр) ? Входной массив термов записан в

```
ArrayList<String> ProcessedTherms = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: @ivan89: а как вы обращаетесь к базе?

Comment: @VladD мне сказали действовать как на http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html и других страницах, приведенных в ответе на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679514/call-of-function-of-a-database-from-the-java-program . Также мне посоветовали посмотреть на http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbccallablestatement.html и http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/ .

Comment: @ivan89: а количество параметров известно заранее?

Comment: @VladD массив термов может иметь любую размерость, параметра у функции 2 - массив термов и `perceptron_id integer` .

Comment: @ivan89: А функции в PostgreSQL умеют принимать массив как параметр? Разве там не обязательны лишь SQL-типы? Или в PostgreSQL массив является встроенным типом? (Я не знаток PostgreSQL.)

Comment: @VladD эту функцию писал не я, а знающий человек, значит сигнатура функции (см. выше) наверняка допустимая.

Comment: @ivan89: и правда, есть. Вот это должно вам помочь: http://stackoverflow.com/q/570393/276994

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда у [[@ivan89](/users/4705/ivan89)](/users/4705/ivan89) вопросы весьма и весьма туманные, приходится догадываться, так что излагаю ответ в меру своего понимания вопроса. А вопрос я понял так:

Как из Java вызвать хранимую процедуру в Postgres где имеются 2 параметра: один в виде массива, а второй целое значение.

Отвечаю:

Копать нужно в сторону [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), примерно так:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(
    "{call net_train(?, ?)}");
ArrayList<String> myTerms;
//Преобразуем термы в строковое представление массива
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("\'{"); //'{
for(String s:myTerms) {
   sb.append("\"").append(s).append("\"").append(','); //пишем нечто вроде "термN", 
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); //убираем последнюю запятую
sb.append("}\'"); // }'
cstmt.setString(1, sb.toString());
cstmt.setInt(2, perceptron_id);
cstmt.executeQuery();
```

Писал на коленках, просьба сильно не бить ногами. По идее Postres должен распарсить строковое представление массива в собственно массив - по крайней мере [документация говорит](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) именно так.